# php-sdk sometimes doesn't connect to facebook but rarely and for no apparent reason

Tags: facebook, cookies, facebook-php-sdk

I have been using php-sdk to connect to facebook for a while and I never had any problems, but now, I can't connect from my computer.
But other people can connect from their computers, I asked a lot of people to confirm and they all said it worked fine..
..can facebook put a ban on my ip or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a ban, it happens when the auth cookie get's messed up on your local machine. It either just hangs when you try log in or continuously redirects.

My suggestion would be to create a page, include the PHP FB SDK make the following call:

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

That *should* get it working again. (well, it does for me)